# Iteración de un segundo elemento

Tags: python

Hola soy nuevo programando en Python tengo un problema sencillo, puede parecer tonto pero, mi pregunta a base de un bucle for en una lista como podría iterar desde un segundo, tercero, cuarto o quinto elemento.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
Elementos=['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k']
for i in Elementos:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar indexación de listas por rangos para iterar un subconjunto de la lista original de la siguiente manera

```
Elementos=['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k']
primer_indice_inclusivo = 3
ultimo_indice_exclusivo = len(Elementos)
for i in Elementos[primer_indice_inclusivo:ultimo_indice_exclusivo ]:
    print(i)
```

El que te mostré es el caso general.

Sin embargo, puedes lograr obtener exactamente lo que deseas utilizando una forma más compacta aun:

```
Elementos=['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k']
primer_indice_inclusivo = 3
for i in Elementos[primer_indice_inclusivo:]:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta